Keep button visible after click to change graph
When I click on the buttons to change the graph they become invisible, but are still usable. How do you keep them always displayed on the window? I know it's plt.clf() that clears the content, but how to place buttons that will always stay under the graph?
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

def plot1(event):
    plt.clf()
    plt.scatter(liste_x,liste_graphe_1,s=5,c="red")
    plt.draw()

def plot2(event):
    plt.clf()
    plt.scatter(liste_x,liste_graphe_2,s=5,c="green")
    plt.draw()

liste_x=[1,2,3]
liste_graphe_1=[1,2,3]
liste_graphe_2=[3,2,1]

fig,ax=plt.subplots()

plt.scatter(liste_x,liste_graphe_1,s=5,c="red")

axBtn1=plt.axes([0.0,0.0,0.2,0.05])
Btn1=Button(axBtn1,label="graphe_1",color="grey",hovercolor="yellow")
Btn1.on_clicked(plot1)

axBtn2=plt.axes([0.2,0.0,0.2,0.05])
Btn2=Button(axBtn2,label="graphe_2",color="grey",hovercolor="yellow")
Btn2.on_clicked(plot2)

plt.show()

Buttons are placed, they change the graph as expected. I tried to take off plt.clf(), but the graphs are not replaced without this function.

if you use the same type of plot (e.g scatter) then you should only replace data instead of drawing new plot. Plot should be assigned to ax and as I remember it may have ax.data which you may replace to get new data on plot without using scatter(). BWT this method can be used to animate plot.

You have to use ax. instead of plt..
First you have to use it to create plot ax.scatter(...)
Next you have to use it to remove plot ax.clear()
# PEP8: use space after `,` around `=`, etc.

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

def plot1(event):
    ax.clear()
    ax.scatter(liste_x, liste_graphe_1, s=5, c="red")
    plt.draw()

def plot2(event):
    ax.clear()
    ax.scatter(liste_x, liste_graphe_2, s=5, c="green")
    plt.draw()

liste_x = [1, 2, 3]
liste_graphe_1 = [1, 2, 3]
liste_graphe_2 = [3, 2, 1]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.scatter(liste_x, liste_graphe_1, s=5, c="red")

ax_btn1 = plt.axes([0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 0.05])  # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for variables
btn1 = Button(ax_btn1, label="graphe_1", color="grey", hovercolor="yellow")
btn1.on_clicked(plot1)

ax_btn2 = plt.axes([0.2, 0.0, 0.2, 0.05])
btn2 = Button(ax_btn2, label="graphe_2", color="grey", hovercolor="yellow")
btn2.on_clicked(plot2)

plt.show()

PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code
